# Adding a non persisted Symfony form checkbox mess up with persistence

Tags: forms, symfony, checkbox, persist

I am trying to add a checkbox in my form in Symfony.
The aim of that checkbox is to eventually remove uploaded image if checked.
So it shows up only when a file is uploaded. I also want it to cancel upload before form entity is persisted.
But I am not there yet, the code that is supposed to do that is currently commented out.
This checkbox corresponds to a boolean property in my File class so that it allows to access its value in controller. At the beginning that property didn't exist  and so I was unable to access this value from entity or form /getData.

My problem is having the field in my formtype messes up with persistence.
All properties  acquired from  the form are considered null by doctrine. Even though a file was selected, renamed with uniqid etc . When time has come to flush, the fields are considered null. Removing DeleteFile from form solved the issue. I have tried setting it with property mapped = false, to no avail.

Here is code from form:

```
 public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('file', 'file', array(
                'label' => false
            ))
        ->add('deleteFile','checkbox', array(
                'label' => 'Delete File',
                'attr' => array('class' => 'delete_file'),
                'mapped' => false,
            ))
    ;
}
```

Thank you for your input. I am also open to alternative solutions to that "interface" if a better solution can spare me from having to deal with this issue I am interested.

Comment: I'd like to have some input on what I am trying to do. is it a nonsense? I am considering doing it with a JavaScript hack...